# Using useState with React and initialise it with blank object in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am fetching details from my api(JSON format). then using useState I am trying to get the Whenever I use the following code I get error .

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not
>   of type 'number'.  TS7015

```
const [myObj, setObj] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/myAPI/1')
            .then((res) => {
                setObj( res.data);

            })
            .catch(err => {
            })

        return ( <span> {myObj["myHeading"]} </span> 
);
}
```

In the API returns an json object like this

```
{id: 1, myHeading: "Heading1"}
```

Comment: You're initializing your state as an `Array` which doesn't support numeric indexes. Initialize it as an `object` and ts will infer the correct type: `useState({ })`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already did that. It gives me the same error. Please note that I am doing this in TSX file

Comment: I've noticed that. How about declaring a dictionary `type D = { [i: string] : any }`; `useState<D>({  })`

Comment: @Dupocas That is great. This really worked.  Also I added more objects in my json. It worked pretty well. You are awesome !!

Comment: hahahah Glad to hear! Good luck